# Comparing corresponding elements of two equal-length arrays

Tags: functional-programming, typescript, lodash.js

I have a helper function I wrote, but it feels like something `_.lodash` already does or could do if I knew the library better.

```
function changed(before:any[], after:any[]):boolean[]
{
    if (before.length !== after.length)
    {
        throw new Error(`Length of arrays are not equivalent: ${before.length}, ${after.length}`);
    }
    else
    {
        let changed:boolean[] = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < before.length; i++)
        {
            changed[i] = (after[i] !== before[i]);
        }
        return changed;
    }
}
```

An example of how this might be used and what would return:

```
console.log(changed([0,1,0,1], [0,1,1,0]))
// => [false, false, true, true]
```

Does anyone know if this can be elegantly achieved with lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know TypeScript or lodash, but I hope the following code is at least almost correct. You should be able to use `zip` and `map` to solve the problem in a functional manner.

```
function changed(a, b) {
    return _.zip(a, b).map(x => { return x[0] !== x[1] });
}
```

Basically, the problem of what has changed can be rephrased as which elements are equal.

Comment: For not knowing lodash, that almost worked perfectly. Small adjustment: `_.zip(a, b).map(x => { return x[0] !== x[1] });`. Without the `return` it will always return `[undefined, ...]`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TroyWeber Ah you got me! Haven't used JS in a while :)

Comment: I'm a newb (going on 4 mo), so I really appreciated your help.